# UWP xaml media element vs HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, xaml, video, win-universal-app, mediaelement

Which one is better overall? most importantly which one of them can play more formats? using 'ffmpeg' can both of them play all formats? including 'flv' and 'mkv'? Which one can be easily customized considering user interface of the player.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. the HTML5 video tag is a standards compliant playback solution that supports EME and MSE. MediaElement is Windows specific and has additional capabilities because of platform integration. Both can be customized (by replacing the controls).

Comment: I want to make a player which can play majority of the media file types and is easily customizable